# "The specified key byte array is 192 bits which is not secure enough for any JWT HMAC-SHA algorithm... " error for mockmvc post request

Tags: key, hmac, mockmvc, http-error, rfc

I want to call write below code to write integration test for login in Kotlin:

```
@Test
fun userSignup() {
    var result  = this.mockMvc.perform(post("http://localhost/signup")
        .content("{\"email\" : \"email\", " +
                "\"username\" : \"username\", " +
                "\"password\" : \"password\", " +
                "\"userType\" : \"artist\"}")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("Authorization", Base64() )
    )
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
}
```

But I get an HTTP status 400 with error message saying:

"The specified key byte array is 192 bits which is not secure enough for any JWT HMAC-SHA algorithm.  The JWT JWA Specification (RFC 7518, Section 3.2) states that keys used with HMAC-SHA algorithms MUST have a size >= 256 bits (the key size must be greater than or equal to the hash output size).  Consider using the io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys#secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm) method to create a key guaranteed to be secure enough for your preferred HMAC-SHA algorithm.  See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3.2 for more information."

How can I resolve this error?

I was expecting a Http 200 status. This error message is too low level that I wouldn't expect to see while working with an abstract library on testing.

Answer (score 6):

please put **quite a big key** for the secret. then it will be okay.

Answer (score 2):

The problems seems to be as follows:
I was using Spring Framework. It has an application.properties file in it. There is a field there with name "security.jwt.secret-key" which is utilized while sending a packet to the network. The encryption of the packets can be done by the algorithms mentioned in error message such as HMAC-SHA algorithm and the algorithm demands a key as some sort of seed to this encryption algorithm from me. The value I provided for that field is too short and this is creating the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the secretKey's value in a secretKey variable inside the class and get it out of your application.proporties or application.yml

private String secretKey = "9a4f2c8d3b7a1e6f45c8a0b3f267d8b1d4e6f3c8a9d2b5f8e3a9c8b5f6v8a3d9";

Comment: I don’t see how that solves the problem they asked. The issue isn’t that they don’t know how to pass the secret key, but that their secret key isn’t being accepted. Further, even if the question was how to ask it, telling them how to set a string variable does _not_ tell them how to access it from their `application.properties` or `application.yml`. Really, it’s unclear how this answer has any relevance here outside of the fact that the variable is named `secretKey`; it shows no attempt to address the specifics of the question.